# Trouble printing to a Brother HL3170CDW printer on Linux

Tags: linux, printing, cups, printer, brother

As the title says, I can't print to my Brother HL3170CDW printer. I'm on Artix Linux (runit version) and have the drivers installed from the AUR. `system-config-printer` detects the printer, and I'm able to add it in that frontend. However, when I try to print anything at all, no data is received. The error logs say `No pages found!`. The full error log is below:

```
E [15/Feb/2021:08:47:46 -0500] Unknown directive JobPrivateAccess on line 121 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [15/Feb/2021:08:47:46 -0500] Unknown directive JobPrivateValues on line 122 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [15/Feb/2021:08:47:46 -0500] Unknown directive SubscriptionPrivateAccess on line 123 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [15/Feb/2021:08:47:46 -0500] Unknown directive SubscriptionPrivateValues on line 124 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
W [15/Feb/2021:08:47:46 -0500] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited:Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
W [15/Feb/2021:08:47:46 -0500] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited:Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
W [15/Feb/2021:08:47:46 -0500] CreateDevice failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited:Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
E [15/Feb/2021:08:47:46 -0500] [Job 80] No pages found!
```

I removed the `JobPrivateAccess`, `JobPrivateValues`, `SubscriptionPrivateAccess`, and `SubscriptionPrivateValues` directives from my `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` but it seems that they reappeared. The concerning part comes from the next few lines about `CreateDevice` and `CreateProfile`.

Also, I am certain that it isn't a permissions issue, since I tried printing a test page as root and it still didn't work.

Has anyone else had this problem and solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: It appears that something messed up my configuration file and that was solved by copying `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf.default` into `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` and `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf.O`.

I initially thought it had something to do with colord not playing nice with runit, and spent a few days messing around with that. Whatever it was, colord seemed to have nothing to do with the printer problem after some research. A little bit after that, I tried to manually modify the config file myself which didn't help at all. Moral of the story: when in doubt, try the defaults.